# Killing-Form of SL_1(Q)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to calculate the Killing-Form for SL$_1(Q)$, with $Q = \langle \langle a,b \rangle \rangle$ being a non split quaternion algebra over a field $k$ of characteristic zero, for practise and better understanding.
I am aware that this is well known and (roughly?) equal to the norm form on $Q$ minus $\langle 1 \rangle$ and thus $-aX^2 -bY^2 abZ^2$.

For this I consider four $4 \times 4$ matrices as given in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.01053.pdf on page 4.

Then I calculate $ad_{()}$ for each of the base elements.

For example $ad_i(x)$ is given by $[i, x] = ix - xi$.

I obtain the structure constants via

$[i,j] = -2k$

$[i,k] = -2a$

$[k,j] = -2b$

equating to $-2, -2a, -2b$. The antisymmetry of the Lie Bracket gives the other non zero values.

The values like $[1, i]$ or $[j,j]$ are all zero.

From these I obtain matrices

$ad_i = [[0,0,0,-2a], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,-2,0]$

$ad_j = [[0,0,0,-2b], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,-2,0,0]$

$ad_k = [[0,2a,2b,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0], [0,0,-2,0]$.

Now I need to calculate all products like $ad_i * ad_j$ and take the trace.

I should now obtain a matrix with non zero entries, from which I can read of the coeffients of the Killing form.

Problem: The trace of each of the products $ad_x * ad_y$ is zero. The products themselfs are not of course.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: A much better summary of and introduction to quaternion algebras than some random arXiv preprint is https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ringtheory/quaternionalg.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, assuming $ij=k$, $i^2=a$ and $j^2=b$, I get $[i,j]=2k, [i,k]=2aj$ and $[k,j]=2bi$.

This gives me e.g. for $ad_i$ the matrix

$$\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&2a\\0&0&2&0}$$

(with respect to the basis $(1,i,j,k)$).

Then, if I multiply out the matrices thus gotten for $ad_i, ad_j$ and $ad_k$ in the basis $(1,i,j,k)$ (or just $(i,j,k)$), indeed I get something of trace zero if I multiply two distinct ones (meaning they are pairwise orthogonal to each other w.r.t. the Killing form); but I get

$tr(ad_i \circ ad_i)= 8a, \qquad tr(ad_j \circ ad_j)=8b, \qquad \text{and} \qquad tr(ad_k \circ ad_k)= -8ab$

which in my eyes makes the Killing form look up to scaling pretty much like $-aX^2-bY^2+abZ^2$.

Comment: The link wasnt that random, I wanted to provide a source for the matrices. If one uses these, one gets structure constants with negative signs. Maybe that was the initial flaw. Say, which matrices did you obtain for $ad_i$ for example?

Comment: See edit. And yes, there seems to be one sign error in the matrices on p. 4 of your source: If they express multiplication from the left with $1,u,v,uv$ respectively; and in each of them, the basis chosen is (from left to right) $uv,v,u,1$, then the first two and the last are consistent, but in the third one (multiplication from the left with $v$), with the $\beta$'s, the signs are exactly wrong i.e. that one should be replaced by its negative.

Comment: I see there was a error in the ressource. Thus my question is answered. Thanks. I didnt find any reference for concrete calculations of Killing-Forms for (non split!) algebraic groups (except $F_4$ and some $E_6$ and $E_8$ cases). In case you know any references, dont hesitate to post them.

Comment: Oh, I would be highly interested in those myself! Do you have any lead in the case of higher dimensional division algebras, i.e. anisotropic forms of type $A_{\ge 2}$? (This here is the case $A_1$.)

Comment: I know that this was the $A_1$ case. I never thought about the higher ones. Shouldnt you find something, when searching for the norm form of a division algebra?

Comment: That's an idea, but the obvious problem is that the norm form is of degree $n=$ degree of the division algebra, while the Killing form is still quadratic i.e. of degree $2$. I know you did not say they are the same, but I see a big gap between them. Or what do I overlook?

Comment: Why dont you start with considering the isomorphism $A_3 \simeq D_3$? The KillingForm for $SO_{2n}$ can be found here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.04261.pdf in $\S 3$. If you know/find the norm form of $PGL_4$, you can check how much the forms we talk about differ.